# Why does it seem like (at least some) ancient European languages didn't have words for "yes" and "no"?

Tags: historical-linguistics, vocabulary

This is something that's bothered me since learning Latin in high school a decade or so ago--it seems like the concepts of "yes" and "no" that I, as a native speaker of English, consider extremely basic, simply didn't exist in at least a few major ancient languages.

Examples I'm aware of:

- Latin generally had the verb repeated in the reply, and I was taught in school that the closest translations to plain "yes" and "no" were "ita vero" (something along the lines of "it is truly so") and "minime" (which I understand means something more like "absolutely not!") (though I suspect these may not have been terribly idiomatic)
- In accordance with the above, many (all?) Romance languages appear to get their words for yes from unrelated Latin words, such as Spanish *sí* from Latin *sic* ("thus", "so"), or French *oui* from Latin *hoc ille* ("this one", I think?) (note that the words for no seem to usually come from the negation particle *non*, though I'm not sure when this came to mean no in Latin)
- The word "yes" in English apparently originates from something in Old English that means more literally "so be it"

Is the idea of having words dedicated to expressing affirmation or denial a comparatively new concept to Indo-European languages? Or is my sample merely too small (it *is* only two really separate cases), and there were actually dedicated words for such in other branches of Indo-European, just not in Latin or Old English?

Comment: There are still plenty of languages in existence that don’t have basic words for yes and/or no. For example, Finnish has no simple ‘no’ (though it does have a special verb used for negation, which is also used for ‘no’), Chinese has no simple ‘yes’, and most of the remaining Celtic languages have neither. Some languages have more than two (most commonly distinguishing ‘yes [to a positive question]’ and ‘no [to a negative question]’), including French (_oui/si_); English used to make the positive/negative distinction in both yes and no and so had _four_ words: pos. yea, nay; neg. yes, no.

Comment: Because a language doesn't have a word for something does not mean speakers do not have the concept. It just means the language uses a different way to express the concept.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I'm not arguing that. The only place I mentioned having a concept was asking if the idea of *having words for yes and no* is new. The concept of having words for them, not the concepts themselves.

Comment: Have a look here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/how-do-you-say-yes-and-no-in-classical-latin